# Date formatting for X-axis labels only showing as 'Jan'

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to create a line chart where the x-axis is in the format of "Month Year" (ex Jun 2014), but instead of showing the month of the actual data point the ticks are all showing as `**Jan**` and the labels don't match up with the plot points.

I am expecting there to be 3 XLabels for **`Jun 2014, Jun 2015, Jun 2016`** but instead, there are only 2 labels for `Jan` in between.

```
var data1 = [{
    x: '06/01/2014',
    y: 1853
}, {
    x: '06/01/2015',
    y: 5087
}, {
    x: '06/01/2016',
    y: 3078
}];

data1.forEach(function(el, i) {
    data1[i].x = new Date(el.x).getTime();
});

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'area'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        labels: {
            formatter: function(){
            return Highcharts.dateFormat("%b %Y", this.value)
          }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Data',
        data: data1
    }]
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ytx8qdoh/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of `tickPositioner`:

```
    xAxis: {
        tickPositioner: function() {
            return this.series[0].xData;
        },
        ...
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/of7k0vxh/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickPositioner